# Update published app to Google play store(Regarding keystore)

Tags: android, google-play-services

I need help.

I published app on play store, and now I forgot password of signed keystore,but I have to update the same app to play store.

Is there any way to retrieve keystore password or any other solution for update app to play store.

please share any good or bad idea.

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic/

Answer (score 1):

**Keystore is as important as the source code.**

Once you lost it( or forgot the password) you are SCREWED..

Please refer this [link](http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/launch-checklist.html#marketupgrade).

So if you've lost the keys, you need to create a new application.